# Routing telemetry messages from Azure IoT Hub to Data Lake store using AZURE function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-iot-hub

How can we route telemetry messages from Azure IOT Hub to Data Lake store using AZURE function.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use Azure Function with IoT Hub trigger to process messages and transfer to Data Lake Store.

There are an offical blog [`How to use Azure Functions with IoT Hub message routing`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-use-azure-functions-with-iot-hub-message-routing/) introduce how to set up Azure Functions with IoT Hub message routing and an existing SO thread [Azure Functions - how to set up IoTHubTrigger for my IoTHub messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743156/azure-functions-how-to-set-up-iothubtrigger-for-my-iothub-messages) which you can refer to.

Then you just need to process messsages from IoTHub and use Data Lake Storage SDK (for example [using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk)) to transfer to Data Lake Store.

Also, using [Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-introduction) for some simple cases is a simple & better solution via [query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns) like SQL without any code in programming to route messages from IoTHub to Data Lake Store.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It would be good if we have sample azure function code to authenticate and create file in ADLS from azure function